# Firebase push notification doesn't use Android string resource from body_loc_key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a backend server that pushes cloud messages to iOS and Android devices. In the messages, the `body_loc_key` attribute is set to `someone_commented_moment`, and `body_loc_args` contains three string arguments.
The Firebase documentation says about the `body_loc_key`:

> On Android, use the key in the app's string resources when populating this value.

So on Android, I have a strings.xml which contains this entry:

```
<resources>
    [...]
    <string name="someone_commented_moment">
        \@%1$s also commented on \@%2$s\'s moment: %3$s
    </string>
    [...]
</resources>
```

Regardless, this string resource is never loaded in the notification that is shown on the device.

On iOS this works flawlessly, and I do get the notification payload in the Intent that starts my Activity from the notification, so I suppose it's not an error on the server side. Am I missing something here? Do I have to manually do something to make this work, to make Firebase find and use that string resource for the localization of the notification body?

Edit:
The python code triggering the notification looks like this:

```
self.fcm.notify_multiple_devices(registration_ids=push_tokens,
                                 body_loc_args=notification.body_loc_args,
                                 message_body=notification.type,
                                 data_message=notification.data,
                                 body_loc_key=notification.type,
                                 sound="default")
```

Where `self.fcm` is an object of type `pyfcm.FCMNotification`, and `notification.type` is set to `"someone_commented_moment"`, as is confirmed by a print statement as well as by what gets sent to the device.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful if you also include the snippet on how you are building the notification (where you use the string resource key).

Comment: @AL. Thanks for the suggestion, I have updated the question with the python code responsible for sending the notification. Any idea on why this doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry wasn't able to respond fast. Seems you were able to figure it out just now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright I found what was making the trouble, by manually trying different requests against the FCM server. It seems that Android won't use the string resource in the `body_loc_key` if the "normal" message body is also set - we have to let the server leave out the message body now when pushing to an Android device.

Comment: just found the same solution. But still, thanks for noting this!

Comment: Is it still the case?

Comment: @RezaBigdeli No idea, not working on that project anymore and can't try it. I'll see if I can get a colleague to comment on this.

Comment: It seems when sending `body_loc_key` without a "normal" message body, Android would show a blank notification to the user if the key is not found in the string resources. This means, users receiving a new notification on a previous version of the app would no see any text. Isn't there a better option to fix this issue?