# How to get values of object notification from firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

The server send me data in notification like this :

```
{    "to" : "xxxxxxxxxx",  
     "notification": 
       {
         "badge": "1",
         "bodyLocArgs": "['XXXX']",
         "bodyLocKey": "AAA.BBB.CCC",
         "image": "url_image",
         "sound": "default"
       },
    "data": {
        "friend": "5dde6ffe47f65624004556d1",
        "type": "FRA"
    } }
```

in my function `onMessageReceived` I can't get values of object `"notification"`, I tried `remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()` but it gives me always **null**, in `remoteMessage.getData()` I found only object `"data"` with "friend" and "type", so my question is how to get object `"notification"`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending this format of notification works great for me, in background, forground and killed app, the problem was in the child "notification"

```
{    "to" : "xxxxxxxxxx",  

    "data": {
         "badge": "1",
         "bodyLocArgs": "['XXXX']",
         "bodyLocKey": "AAA.BBB.CCC",
         "image": "url_image",
         "sound": "default"
         "friend": "5dde6ffe47f65624004556d1",
         "type": "FRA"
    } }
```

in `remotemessage.getData()` I found all my notification values.

Answer (score 0):

The notification doesn't have body or title. So .getBody() is always null.

You can use like this:

```
String bodyLocKey = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBodyLocalizationKey();
String [] bodyLocArgs = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBodyLocalizationArgs();
```

---

```
 remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(); // null
 remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(); // null
```

more [methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.Notification#public-method-summary)

Comment: Your notification does not contain bodyLocArgs. click three dots

Comment: 3 dots are not clickable, there's any way to get the first values ? how I can get that zza ?

Comment: There is no way. There is another mistake. bodyLocKey should not be null

Comment: can you look at [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39342966/8956604)